# How can I send html email with style to yahoo email app?

Tags: html, css, yahoo

I have using the following html code to send the Email to the users in php. But it looks better in Gmail PC and mobile app.

But the styles are not wrapped in yahoo app.

I also checked the `<style>` in the `<body>` too. But the same problem.

```css
      <!-- START CSS STYLES - These should be inline before sending! -->
      <style>
         /* RESET */
         img, img a {
         border: none;
         max-width: 100%;
         outline: none;
         /* Fix resized images in IE */
         -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
         }
         body {
         background-color: #4F2A93;
         font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
         font-size: 1rem; /* 16px */
         line-height: 1.5; /* 24px */
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         /* Render fonts consistently */
         -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
         /* Fix text resizing on mobile */
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         }
         hr {
         border: 0;
         border-bottom: 1px solid #EDECEE;
         margin: 1.25rem 0;
         }
         table {
         border: none;
         border-collapse: separate;
         border-spacing: 0;
         width: 100%;
         /* Remove Outlook's added spacing on tables */
         mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
         mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
         }
         table td {
         font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
         font-size: 1rem;
         vertical-align: top;
         }
         /* BODY & CONTAINER */
         .body {
         background-color: #4F2A93;
         width: 100%;
         }
         .container {
         display: block; /* Automatically stretch to max-width */
         margin: 0 auto !important; /* Center */
         max-width: 35rem; /* 560px */
         padding: .5rem;
         width: 35rem;
         }
         .content {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         display: block; /* Fill 100% of .container */
         margin: 0 auto;
         max-width: 35rem;
         padding: 0;
         }
         /* Header, Footer & Main */
         .preheader {
         color: transparent;
         display: none;
         height: 0;
         max-height: 0;
         max-width: 0;
         opacity: 0;
         overflow: hidden;
         mso-hide: all;
         visibility: hidden;
         width: 0;
         }
         .logo {
         display: block;
         margin: 1rem 0 .5rem 0;
         padding: 0;
         text-align: center; 
         }
         .logo img { max-height: 4.5rem !important; }
         .header-image { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
         .main {
         background-color: #FFFFFF;
         border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
         width: 100%;
         }
         .wrapper {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 0 1.5rem;
         }
         .bullets {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0 3rem 0 1rem;
         }
         .bullets img {
         min-height: 3rem !important;
         min-width: 3rem !important;
         }
         .bullets p {
         margin: 0 0 1.5rem 1rem;
         padding: 0;
         }
         .app-footer {
         background-color: #F9F9F9;
         border-radius: 0 0 .5rem .5rem;
         padding: 1rem 0 0 0;
         text-align: center;
         }
         .app-footer img {
         margin: 0 .375rem .25rem .375rem;
         max-height: 2rem !important;
         }
         .app-footer p {
         color: #686274;
         font-size: .75rem; /* 12px */
         line-height: 1.34; /* 16px */
         margin-bottom: .75rem;
         }
         .content-block {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         }
         .footer {
         clear: both;
         margin: .5rem 0 1.5rem 0;
         text-align: center;
         width: 100%
         }
         .footer p,
         .footer td,
         .footer span,
         .footer a {
         color: #BDA8FF;
         font-size: .75rem;
         line-height: 1.34;
         margin: 0;
         text-align: center;
         }
         .footer a { text-decoration: underline; }
         .footer img { max-height: 2rem !important; }
         /* Typography */
         h1,
         h2,
         h3,
         h4 {
         color: #34313A; /* Outlook heading color override */
         font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
         font-weight: 400;
         margin: 0;
         margin-bottom: 1rem;
         }
         h1 {
         color: #686274;
         font-size: 1.25rem;
         line-height: 1.2;
         text-align: center;
         /* text-transform: capitalize; */
         }
         p,
         ul,
         ol {
         color: #34313A;
         font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
         font-size: 1rem;
         font-weight: normal;
         line-height: 1.5;
         list-style-position: outside;
         margin: 0 0 1.5rem 0;
         }
         p li,
         ul li,
         ol li { margin-bottom: .5rem; }
         a {
         color: #2995CD;
         text-decoration: none;
         }
         .small-caps {
         color: #EE9109;
         font-size: .75rem;
         font-weight: 600;
         line-height: 1.34;
         margin: 1rem 0 .5rem 0;
         }
         /* Buttons */
         .btn {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         width: 100%;
         }
         .btn > tbody > tr > td { padding-bottom: 1.5rem; }
         .btn table { width: auto; }
         .btn table td {
         background-color: #FFFFFF;
         border-radius: .25rem;
         text-align: center;
         }
         .btn a {
         background-color: #FFFFFF;
         border: none;
         border-radius: .25rem;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         color: #2995CD;
         cursor: pointer;
         display: inline-block;
         font-size: 1rem;
         font-weight: 600;
         margin: 0;
         padding: .875rem 2rem;
         text-decoration: none;
         }
         .btn-primary table td { background-color: #2995CD; }
         .btn-primary a {
         background-color: #2995CD;
         border-color: #2995CD;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         }
         /* Responsive */
         @media only screen and (max-width: 40rem) {
         table[class=body] .logo,
         table[class=body] .header-image { margin-bottom: .5rem !important; }
         table[class=body] .logo img { max-height: 4rem !important; }
         table[class=body] h1 {
         font-size: 1.25rem !important;
         line-height: 1.4 !important;
         margin-bottom: 1rem !important;
         }
         table[class=body] p,
         table[class=body] ul,
         table[class=body] ol,
         table[class=body] td,
         table[class=body] span,
         table[class=body] a {
         font-size: .875rem !important;
         line-height: 1.34 !important;
         }
         table[class=body] ul, ol { padding-left: 1.5rem !important; }
         table[class=body] .wrapper,
         table[class=body] .article { padding: 1rem 1rem 0 1rem !important; }
         table[class=body] .content { padding: 0 1rem !important; }
         table[class=body] .container {
         padding: 0 !important;
         width: 100% !important;
         }
         table[class=body] .main {
         border-left-width: 0 !important;
         border-radius: .25rem .25rem 0 0 !important;
         border-right-width: 0 !important;
         }
         .bullets {
         margin: 0 !important;
         padding: 0 1rem 0 0 !important;
         }
         .bullets img {
         display: none !important;
         height: 0 !important;
         max-height: 0 !important;
         max-width: 0 !important;
         opacity: 0 !important;
         overflow: hidden !important;
         mso-hide: all !important;
         visibility: hidden !important;
         width: 0 !important;
         }
         table[class=body] .btn table,
         table[class=body] .btn a { width: 100% !important; }
         table[class=body] .img-responsive {
         height: auto !important;
         max-width: 100% !important;
         width: auto !important;
         }
         }
         /* Outlook / Hotmail */
         @media all {
         .ExternalClass{ width: 100%; }
         .ExternalClass,
         .ExternalClass p,
         .ExternalClass span,
         .ExternalClass font,
         .ExternalClass td,
         .ExternalClass div {
         line-height: 100%;
         }
         .social-link a {
         color: inherit !important;
         font-family: inherit !important;
         font-size: inherit !important;
         font-weight: inherit !important;
         line-height: inherit !important;
         text-decoration: none !important;
         }
         }
         /* new for invoice*/
         .invoice-box {
         max-width: 800px;
         margin: auto;
         padding: 30px;
         border: 1px solid #eee;
         box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
         font-size: 16px;
         line-height: 24px;
         font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
         color: #555;
         }
         .invoice-box table {
         width: 100%;
         line-height: inherit;
         text-align: left;
         }
         .invoice-box table td {
         padding: 5px;
         vertical-align: top;
         }
         .invoice-box table tr td:nth-child(2) {
         text-align: right;
         }
         .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
         padding-bottom: 20px;
         }
         .invoice-box table tr.top table td.title {
         font-size: 45px;
         line-height: 45px;
         color: #333;
         }
         .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
         padding-bottom: 40px;
         }
         .invoice-box table tr.heading td {
         background: #eee;
         border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
         font-weight: bold;
         }
         .invoice-box table tr.details td {
         padding-bottom: 20px;
         }
         .invoice-box table tr.item td {
         border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
         }
         .invoice-box table tr.item.last td {
         border-bottom: none;
         }
         .invoice-box table tr.total td:nth-child(2) {
         border-top: 2px solid #eee;
         font-weight: bold;
         }
         @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
         .invoice-box table tr.top table td {
         width: 100%;
         display: block;
         text-align: center;
         }
         .invoice-box table tr.information table td {
         width: 100%;
         display: block;
         text-align: center;
         }
         }
      </style>
      <!-- END CSS STYLES -->
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <title>Welcome</title>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

   </head>
   <body class="">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body">
         <tr>
            <td class="container">
               <!-- START CENTERED WHITE CONTENT -->
               <div class="content">
                  
                  <div class="logo">
                     <a href="https://www.google.lk" target="_blank"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/1b/Semi-protection-shackle.svg/20px-Semi-protection-shackle.svg.png" alt="Logo"/></a>
                  </div>
                  <table class="main">
                     <!-- START MAIN CONTENT -->
                     <tr>
                        <td class="wrapper">
                           <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <h1>Hello John,</h1>
                                    <hr />
                                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an</p>
                                    <p> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution </p>
                                    <div class="invoice-box">
                                       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                          
                                          <tr class="heading">
                                             <td>
                                                Name
                                             </td>
                                             <td>
                                                Class
                                             </td>
                                             <td>
                                                Address
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          @foreach($data["data"]->Studentdata as $sdata)
                                          <tr class="item">
                                             <td>{{$sdata->name}}</td>
                                             <td>{{$sdata->class}}</td>
                                             <td>{{$sdata->address}}</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          @endforeach
                                          <tr class="total">
                                             <td></td>
                                             <td>
                                                Marks: {{$sdata["data"]->marks}}
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr class="total">
                                             <td></td>
                                             <td>
                                                Total: {{$sdata["data"]->total}}
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </table>
                                    </div> <br/>
                                    <p>Warmly,<br /><strong>Happy team</strong></p>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
                  <div class="app-footer">
                     <table border ="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                           <td>
                              <a href="https://www.happyteam.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/android/market_images/web/play_prism_hlock_2x.png" alt="Download on Google Play"></a>
                              <p>Or visit us on the web <a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a></p>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </div>
              
               </div>
               <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTENT -->
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
</html>
</body>
```

**How it is in gmail (mobile)**

[image: Gmail 1]
[image: Gmail 2]

**How it is in Yahoo (mobile)**

[image: Yahoo]

Answer (score 1):

test team!

I once had similar issue earlier before now.

Try using Inline CSS instead, that should do the trick for both Gmail and Yahoo.